# Split the string by skipping constant value in java

Tags: java, regex

I am getting the key as `DRAVID,RAHUL,DWAYNE,JOHNSON,DAVID` and I want to split strings on commas. Constructed data contains comma, i.e:

```
Key:  DRAVID,RAHUL,DWAYNE,JOHNSON,DAVID
```

And expected result :

```
DRAVID,RAHUL
DWAYNE,JOHNSON
DAVID

String regEx = "(?<!^[^(DRAVID,RAHUL|DWAYNE,JOHNSON)]*),";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str1.split(regEx)));
```

But I am getting below result

```
DRAVID,
RAHUL
DWAYNE,
JOHNSON
DAVID
```

I can  identify the name list before splitting that is `DRAVID,RAHUL` & `DWAYNE,JOHNSON`. Is it possible to split the string by skipping constant predefined names like `DRAVID,RAHUL` ?

Comment: Please someone help me on this

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. Split the string using comma as a delimiter and then what ?

Comment: Key constructed with different names by the delimiter comma but name itself contains comma separator to differentiate first and last name . DRAVID,RAHUL is a single name.

Comment: Split every 2 comma, is that it?

Comment: I cant it may change order DRAVID,RAHUL,DAVID,DWAYNE,JOHNSON . So i cant prefer your solution . I can take names which contains comma like DRAVID,RAHUL and I need to split by skipping the constnt names

Comment: So if it is not regular, how can a regex magically know what is the name?

Comment: I can provide the name which contains comma

Comment: As already said, split on the comma and loop over the results. If you know which names belong together - nice for you. Otherwise this Problem is undecidable: you need to know where to split and where not.

Comment: Thats two different work splitting and looping . I want to do it using regEX